# How to handle Disconnection with Firesharp?

Tags: c#, firebase, fire-sharp

I am using Firesharp for my desktop project and after sometime/randomly maybe for a Wifi issue or something else, the OnAsync method that streams the data "as realtime" stop working.

I need to restart the application (or added a retry button) to reconnect to the Realtime DB again. How can i handle this automatically? exist away to know if i lost the connection to firebase?

Comment: Firebase reconnects automatically - it's built in.

Comment: Yes, but looks like Firesharp doesn’t

Comment: Seems odd. How can a non-blocking asynchronous library that observes changes in the database not re-connect when disconnected? I am also not seeing any bug reports along those lines either. Perhaps you can craft a reproducible example and file a git bug report.

Comment: that is a good idea... because i found out that with a not estable connection this asynchronous library stop working

Comment: I checked that firesharp is based in the Rest API, and the recconection needs to be handle manually, actually i saw a lot of issues about websocket disconnection from firebase...